# JavaFX Scene width and height not working properly

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, fxml

I have this code, which launches a stage in FX:

```
public class ApplicationStart extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/frames/login.fxml"));

        LoginController loginController = new LoginController();
        loader.setController(loginController);

        Parent root = loader.load();
        stage.setTitle("Login");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 400));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

In the login.fxml file, the Pane has the width of 600, and height of 400. And in the code above, I set the width and height of the Scene accordingly.

```
<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/15.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
```

But when I launch the application, the width and height are totally messed up, they are way bigger, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4btX2.png). I tried to reduce the width and height in the code above, trying to debug what is happening, to something like Scene(root, 400, 200). Now it looked ok, but when I clicked on the "Register" button, which is the lower most button, the button doesn't respond, like if I would click outside the window (if I have intellij in the background, for example, and i click the button, the intellij window comes first, and the app window goes back). It's like the app window has some visible bounds, and some actual bounds. The visible bounds are something like width + 200 height + 200, and the actual logical bounds are the exact width and height I set. What can I do to solve this? 
Here's the entire fxml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>

<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/15.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <TextField layoutX="357.0" layoutY="131.0" />
      <PasswordField layoutX="357.0" layoutY="187.0" />
      <Label layoutX="310.0" layoutY="136.0" text="Email:" />
      <Label layoutX="285.0" layoutY="191.0" text="Password:" />
      <Button layoutX="357.0" layoutY="260.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="152.0" style="-fx-background-color: #25b2fd;" text="Log In" />
      <ImageView fx:id="logoImageView" fitHeight="230.0" fitWidth="324.0" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="85.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../../../../images/logo.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <ImageView fx:id="lockImageView" fitHeight="51.0" fitWidth="53.0" layoutX="408.0" layoutY="60.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../../../../images/lock.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <Button layoutX="357.0" layoutY="307.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="152.0" style="-fx-background-color: #25b2fd;" text="Register" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

And here's the LoginController class, but I doubt it will help, it doesn't have much in it other than initializing the images:

```
public class LoginController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private ImageView logoImageView = new ImageView();
    @FXML
    private ImageView lockImageView = new ImageView();

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        File logoFile = new File("images/logo.png");
        Image logoImage = new Image(logoFile.toURI().toString());
        logoImageView.setImage(logoImage);

        File lockFile = new File("images/lock.png");
        Image lockImage = new Image(lockFile.toURI().toString());
        lockImageView.setImage(lockImage);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you consider using [layouts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/index.html)?

Comment: don't do any manual sizing/positioning of nodes .. use appropriate layouts (as @Abra already noted :)